# From an iframe, how to send an XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, xmlhttprequest

1. **iframe load the content from src**
2. How to send a xhr request for & from this iframe, loaded content?

Something like this

```
<iframe src="remote_server.com/upload.php">

xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST, "remote_server.com/upload.php");
xhr.send("data");

</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content between the start and end tag for the iframe element is *alternative content* for browsers which do not support iframes.

You need to put your script in a `<script>` element and put that element in the HTML of the page at `remote_server.com/upload.php`.